# Can I avoid the `eval(parse())` defining a function with `polynomial()` in R?

Tags: r

I want to avoid using `parse()` in a function definition that contains a `polynomial()`.

My polynomial is this:

```
library(polynom)
polynomial(c(1, 2))
# 1 + 2*x
```

I want to create a function which uses this polynomial expression as in:

```
my.function <- function(x) magic(polynomial(c(1, 2)))
```

where for `magic()`, I have tried various combinations of `expression()`, `formula()`, `eval()`, `as.character()`, etc... but nothing seems to work.

My only working solution is using `eval(parse())`:

```
eval(parse(text = paste0('poly_function <- function(x) ', polynomial(c(1, 2)))))

poly_function(x = 10) 
# 21
```

Is there a better way to do want I want? Can I avoid the `eval(parse())`?

Comment: seems there is a function for that `f <- as.function(polynomial(c(1, 2)))`

Comment: @user20650 Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you could easily write your own function too

```
poly_function = function(x, p){
    sum(sapply(1:length(p), function(i) p[i]*x^(i-1)))
}
# As 42- mentioned in comment to this answer,
# it appears that p can be either a vector or a polynomial

pol = polynomial(c(1, 2))
poly_function(x = 10, p = pol)
#[1] 21

#OR
poly_function(x = 10, p = c(1,2))
#[1] 21
```

Comment: If you had written `function(x, p = pol ){` it would have been more general and still succeeded.

Comment: Well, it seems I asked the wrong question. :D Thanks! I wanted to drow polynomial function given different parameters to the `polynomial()` function. It seems using `eval(parse())` is the only way (or use your function and calculate the corresponding data  points). Minimal Working Example: `library(ggplot2); library(polynom); p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), mapping = aes(x = x)); p + stat_function(fun = eval(parse(text = paste0('function(x) ', (polynomial(c(1, 2, 3))))))) + xlim(-50,50)`

Comment: pff so complicated. Sorry I "unaccepted" momentarily the answer because i just found that i can use `as.function` inside the `stat_function()`. So confused. Yes, I know, but I was using the h`polynomial` to "generate" the expression in `curve`.

Answer (score 3):

Like you, I though that the polynomial function was returning an R expression, but we were both wrong. Reading the help Index for package:polynom would have helped us both:

```
str(pol)
#Class 'polynomial'  num [1:2] 1 2
help(pac=polynom)
```

So user20650 is correct and:

```
    > poly_function <- as.function(pol)
    > poly_function(10)
    [1] 21
```

So this was how the authors (Venables, Hornick, Maechler) do it:

```
> getAnywhere(as.function.polynomial)
A single object matching ‘as.function.polynomial’ was found
It was found in the following places
  registered S3 method for as.function from namespace polynom
  namespace:polynom
with value

function (x, ...) 
{
    a <- rev(coef(x))
    w <- as.name("w")
    v <- as.name("x")
    ex <- call("{", call("<-", w, 0))
    for (i in seq_along(a)) {
        ex[[i + 2]] <- call("<-", w, call("+", a[1], call("*", 
            v, w)))
        a <- a[-1]
    }
    ex[[length(ex) + 1]] <- w
    f <- function(x) NULL
    body(f) <- ex
    f
}
<environment: namespace:polynom>
```

Since you mention in your comments that getAnywhere was new then it also might be the case that you could gain by reviewing the "run up" to using it. If you type a function name at the console prompt, you get the code, in this case:

```
> as.function
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("as.function")
<bytecode: 0x7f978bff5fc8>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Which is rather unhelpful until you follow it up with:

```
> methods(as.function)
[1] as.function.default     as.function.polynomial*
see '?methods' for accessing help and source code
```

The asterisk at the end of the `polynomial` version tells you that the code is not "exported", i.e. available at the console just by typing. So you need to pry it out of a loaded namespace with `getAnywhere`.

Comment: Thank you very much! `as.function()` is what I will use and I did not know about `getAnywhere()`. I wanted to plot with ggplot polynomial functions. Minimal Working Example: `library(ggplot2); library(polynom); p <- ggplot(data = data.frame(x = 0), mapping = aes(x = x)); p + stat_function(fun = as.function(polynomial(c(1, 2, 3)))) + xlim(-50,50) `

Comment: Added response to comment that was too long to fit in here.